# How to delete directory named ".."

Tags: windows-7, command-line

On windows 7 I'm having this issue deleting a folder named ".."

I have a folder names ".." located on my desktop

When I run in the CMD the command as follows:

> rmdir /s "\?\C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop..

I get the respond:
    \?\C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop.., Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: `..` refers to the parent directory.  Why on earth would you want to delete it?  FWIW, you could do `cd ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..` and try to figure what's it.

Comment: I know that `..`refers to the parent dir...however, a friend of mine created this direcory in my desktop named ".." which contains the content of my desktop(as it should be) but how can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two dots is just a pointer to the parent folder from within a folder.

If you were successful in deleting .. it would be a bad idea.

What is on your desktop is a shortcut to the folder, not the folder itself.  Just delete the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, it is not an actual folder but the representation of the "parent folder".

> **"cd .."** will move you up one directory. So, if you are /usr/bin/tmp,
>   cd .. moves you to /usr/bin, while cd ../.. moves you to /usr (i.e. up
>   two levels). You can use this indirection to access subdirectories
>   too. So, from /usr/bin/tmp, you can use cd ../../local to go to
>   /usr/local.

Source: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)#Options_.28version_specific.29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_%28command%29#Options_.28version_specific.29)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `\` after Desktop. If that doesn't help, try

```
dir C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
```

Is the FolderName in CMD also ".."?